# Polynomial regression for one input feature

Tags: machine-learning

I am new to machine learning. I am having a question regarding polynomial regression using one feature.

My understanding is that if there is one input feature, we can create a hypothesis function by taking the squares and cubes the feature.

Suppose x1 is the input feature and our hypothesis function becomes something like this :

> htheta(x) = theta0 + (theta1)x1 + (theta2)x1^2 + (theta3)x1^3.

My question is what is the use case of such scenario ? In what type of data, this type of hypothesis function will help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario is for simple curve fitting problems. For example, you might have a spring and want to know how far the spring is stretched as a function of how much force you apply (the spring needn't be a linear spring obeying Hooke's law). You could build a model by collecting a bunch of measurements of different forces applied on the spring (measured in Newtons) and the resulting spring extension (also called displacement) in centimeters. You could then build a model of the form F(x) = theta_1 * x + theta_2 * x^3 + theta_3 * x^5 and fit the three theta parameters. You could of course do this with any other single variable problem (height vs. age, weight vs. blood pressure, current vs. voltage). In practice, you generally have many more than just a one dependent variable though.

Also worth pointing out that the transformations needn't be polynomial in the dependent variable (x in this case). You could just as well try logs, square roots, exponentials etc. If you're asking why is it always a parameter times a function of the input variable, this is more of a modeling choice than anything (specifically a linear model since it's linear in theta). It does not have to be this way and is a simple assumption that restricts the class of functions. Linear models also satisfy some intuitive statistical properties which also justify their use (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model))